# Use Generic type on a Typevar

Tags: python, oop, python-typing

I am building a class decorator that works as well as possible with Python typing.
From the following code:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, List, Type

ExecutorType = TypeVar("ExecutorType")

class Task(Generic[ExecutorType]):
    _executor: ExecutorType

    pass

TaskType = TypeVar("TaskType", bound=Task)
ChildTaskType = TypeVar("ChildTaskType", bound=Task)
ExecutorType = TypeVar("ExecutorType", bound='Executor')

class Executor(Generic[TaskType]):
    _TASKS_CLASSES: List[Type[TaskType]] = []

    @classmethod
    def task(cls: Type[ExecutorType]):
        def decorator(task_cls: Type[ChildTaskType]):
            cls._TASKS_CLASSES.append(task_cls)
            return task_cls
        return decorator
    
class Checker(Executor):
    def checker_method(self):
        return "Check Method"
    pass
```

I need to be able to write the following decorator without any typing errors:

```py
@Checker.task()
class Check(Task):
    def check_method(self):
        self._executor.checker_method()
```

However, when I write this code, `self._executor` is not assigned to `Checker` as I would need it to be (It is still the base Executor class), so `checker_method` is obviously not found. To fix that, I need to specify that `Task` Generic is `Checker` like this:

```py
@Checker.task()
class Check(Task[Checker]):
    ...
```

My question: Is there any way of using typing inside my decorator method `task` to specify that the output's class Generic is `ExecutorType`? In other words, I would need to type my task output as follows `Type[ChildTaskType[Type[ExecutorType]]` but it seems not possible.

Comment: This would require [higher-kinded type variables](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548).

Comment: Oh Indeed, seems like the kind of feature I need, it seems there are no workaround yet though.
Thanks for the answer!